# Appropriate JS data structure for linking three arrays

Tags: javascript, angular

I have three arrays that I need to link to each other in this way:

1. arr1 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C' 'A', 'C']
2. arr2 = ['a', 'aa', 'b', 'bb', 'c', 'cc', 'aaa', 'ccc']
3. arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

I want these arrays to be linked like this: [['A', ['a', 1], ['aa',2], ['aaa',7]], ['B', ['b', 3], ['bb',4]], ['C', ['c', 5], ['cc',6], ['ccc', 8]]

I could create a 2d array like this but I feel it won't be an efficient data structure. Moreover, I will be using HTML to display content from this data structure and the 2d array could get complicated. I was thinking of using a Map but not sure whether it supports arrays as values to the keys. Any ideas/suggestions how I can achieve this?

Comment: How would you propose linking `'A'` with `'a'` and `'aa'`?  Is it simply a 2-for-one deal?

Comment: But why do you think it would be inefficient?  It certainly makes more sense to me than to try to link them together after the fact.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, exactly. 'A' is like a key to 'a' and 'aa'. So you are suggesting to stick with a 2d array then?

Comment: I understand the output.  But how would we know given the original arrays how many elements of `arr2` to link with one from `arr1`?  And yes, I think a complete data structure is significantly better than one in parts you later need to join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update 2

With this version requiring only shared indices in the three arrays, plus some grouping of the results, it's a bit easier:

```js
const link = (a1, a2, a3) =>
  [... new Set (a1)] .map ((a) => [ 
    a,                       
    ...Object.keys(a1) .filter (k => a1[k] == a) .map (k => [a2 [k], a3 [k]])
  ])  

const arr1 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C']
const arr2 = ['a', 'aa', 'b', 'bb', 'c', 'cc', 'aaa', 'ccc']
const arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

console .log (link (arr1, arr2, arr3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I would still strongly recommend that you rethink your data structures.  Shared array indices are a pretty nasty way to deal with data.

I would find this much, much cleaner:

```
[
  {foo: 'A', bars: [{baz: 'a', qux: 1}, {baz: 'aa', qux: 2}, {baz: 'aaa', qux: 7}]},
  {foo: 'B', bars: [{baz: 'b', qux: 3}, {baz: 'bb', qux: 4}]},
  {foo: 'C', bars: [{baz: 'c', qux: 5}, {baz: 'cc', qux: 6}, {baz: 'ccc', qux: 8}]}
]
```

### Explanation

A comment asked for an explanation of this code.  Here's an attempt.

```js
const link = (a1, a2, a3) =>
  [... new Set (a1)] .map ((a) => [ 
    a,                       
    ...Object.keys(a1) .filter (k => a1[k] == a) .map (k => [a2 [k], a3 [k]])
  ])
```

We start by defining `link` as a function of three parameters, `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`.  With realistic data you would likely give these more meaningful names.  Our goal will be to take the three arrays and, using shared indices, pair up the values in each by indices, and then group the results based on the first value, each of which may be duplicated multiple times in the first array.

We could have chosen to use a `crossproduct` implementation to create an intermediate result like `[['A', 'a', '1'], ['A', 'aa', 2], ['B', 'b', 3], ...]` then do the grouping on those values.

Instead we choose to go a little more directly at this.  Our arrow function contains only one expression, so there is no need for `{` - `}` or a `return` statement.  We first create an array of unique members of `a1`, using what's probably the most common implementation of uniqueness: `[... new Set (a1)]`.  Here `new Set (a1)` creates a set, an container without duplicates.  When we prepend it with `...`, we get an iterator for the set.  And wrapping that in `[` - `]` makes it into an array.  That will give us `['A', 'B', 'C']`.

We want an output array containing one output array for each of these, so we can use `map`, which by applying a function to each element turns one array into another of the same size.  The function we pass to `map` takes a value from `['A', 'B', 'C']` and returns an array.  The first element is that value, and the others are found by calling `Object.keys` on our array.  (Logically, `Array.keys` makes more sense here, as it will give us numeric keys.  But that would take one additional step as we'd have to turn its iterator result into an array; and in this case the string keys will work just as well.)  We filter these keys/indices to find those where the values in our original array match the current value.  For `A`, this would be `['0', '1', '6']`.

We `map` again, converting these indices into a pair of same-index values from the other two arrays.  This is `.map (k => [a2 [k], a3 [k]])`.  Finally, we apply a `...` to spread the results into our array.

I hope that helps.

## Updated Version

We have more information now.  If I understand correctly, we will have some way to match a given element from the second array with one from the first array.  Let's encode that in a function, which we can then pass to our generic solution.

Here I demonstrate with the sample data assuming a match is simply a letter match.

```js
const link = (match) => (a1, a2, a3) =>
  a1 .map (x => [
    x, 
    ...Object.keys(a2) .filter (k => match (x, a2[k]))
      .map (k => [a2[k], a3[k]])
  ])  

const arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
const arr2 = ['a', 'aa', 'b', 'bb', 'c', 'cc', 'aaa', 'ccc']
const arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

const matchingLetter = (a1Val, a2Val) => 
  a2Val .startsWith (a1Val.toLowerCase())

console .log (link (matchingLetter) (arr1, arr2, arr3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

## Original Version

As discussed in the comments, this strikes me as a bad idea, if your data sources don't force it upon you.

But if all you need to do is to takes one element from the first array and pair it with a linked set of two pairs from the next two arrays, then you could write something like this:

```js
const link = (a1, a2, a3) =>
  a1 .map ((a, i) => [a, [a2[2 * i], a3[2 * i]], [a2[2 * i + 1], a3[2 * i + 1]]])

const arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
const arr2 = ['a', 'aa', 'b', 'bb', 'c', 'cc']
const arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

console .log (link (arr1, arr2, arr3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

If there is some other relationship between the linked sets than this little two-for-one mapping, then I think we need more information.

Comment: This worked fine for two-for-one but it turns arr2 and arr3 have more than two elements that need to be mapped to one element from arr1. I have updated the question.

Comment: @shasha: I was assuming that these were examples and not your literal data.  Was I wrong about this?  Can you actually link these by spelling, that everything matched with `'A'` has the actual value of some number of `'a'`s, everything matched with `'B'` contains nothing but `'b'`s, and so on?  If not, how would you know that, in your example, `'ccc'` matched with `'C'` and not with `'B'`?

Comment: Your assumption was right, it is not my literal data. arr1 basically contains the 'source' and arr3 contains the 'timestamp' of elements from arr2. Elements from arr1 are basically a key and the value is an array of elements from arr2 and arr3.

Comment: But how do you match them?  How can you tell from the value in `arr2` which element of `arr1` it belongs with?

Comment: I edited the question. I removed duplicates from arr1 which made it confusing, apologies. The elements are pushed sequentially so arr1[0] is the source for arr2[0], arr1[1] is the source for arr2[1] and so on..

Comment: Added an update based on another misunderstanding.  These requirements now are actually easier.  I'll try to code something now.

Comment: Thank you for posting the updated versions. I am a beginner with scripting languages due to which I am a bit confused with some of the functions you have used, for e.g. what is happening in this part```...Object.keys(a1) .filter (k => a1[k] == a)```. I agree with you regarding restructuring my data structures, I'll look into forming a Map instead of arrays.

Comment: @shasha: Added an explanation for that final function.